# Performance monitoring/profiling for python server process (similar to New Relic)

Tags: python, performance, profiling, celery, newrelic

Is there a tool/service that can automatically and perpetually instrument and profile python server processes? I'm thinking about processes like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org/) workers? I'd like to get method-level performance timers averaged across multiple similar job executions.

New Relic will do [this](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/back-end-services/python-agent-celery) for Celery but it only has [experimental support](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/newrelic-rq-unofficial-support/14978/2) for RQ.  Unfortunately it's not recommended for short lived tasks, and we have lots of those.

I'm aware of `cProfile` and `line_profiler`, but I'm hoping to find a service I can use in production where I don't have to capture the output and aggregate it myself.  While a permanent service/tool would be preferred, if there's a tool that will aggregate the output of multiple cProfile runs that might work as well.

BTW the processes are running on Heroku non-web worker dynos.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AppDynamics? It's an APM like NewRelic but support Python (http://www.appdynamics.com/python/)

Comment: No, but it also looks like AppDynamics would not support this scenario.  Their [docs](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO41/Python+Supported+Environments) _(which were a real PITA to find)_ suggest that their Agent only supports WSGI environments, which is basically the same as New Relic.  I need something could be used to monitor/profile a python script.